# Building from Source on MAC OSX 10.9 Error

Tags: bitcoind

Hi i'm building Bitcoin from source and am having some problems. Curious if anyone would be able to help me.

When I try to make I get:

```
In file included from ./json/json_spirit_reader_template.h:9:
./json/json_spirit_value.h:20:10: fatal error: 'boost/config.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/config.hpp>
         ^
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [rpcclient.o] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I try brew install boost and it's saying boost-1.55.0_2 already installed. Any ideas what exatly is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by appending the following code to ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export CPATH=/usr/local/include
```